# radiobutton getleft() returns 0 when repopulate

Tags: java, android

I have one radiogroup with database populated radiobuttons. When I repopulated them with:

```
Radiogroup fofo = (Radiogroup) findViewById(R.id.AperturasRadio);
    fofo.removeAllViews();
    for(int i = 0; i < mStringArray.length ; i++){
            RadioButton newRadioButton;
            newRadioButton = (RadioButton)
            getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.radio_template, null);
            String label = (String) mStringArray[i];
            newRadioButton.setText(label);
            newRadioButton.setId(i);
            if (label.equals("2.8")) {
                newradiobutton.setChecked(true);
            }
            fofo.addView(newRadioButton);
            fofo.updateBackground();
```

The problem is that I have a RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener who triggers a diferent method that need the CheckedRadiobutton.Getleft()

```
    RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener listenerAperturas = new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int id) {

RadioGroup grupo1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.AperturasRadio);
int radioButtonID = grupo1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
RadioButton radiogrButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(radioButtonID);
int left = radiogrButton.getLeft();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Botton radio: " + left + " " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

But the value is 0. The first time radiogroup populates works fine, but when I trigger de repopulation just returns zero.

The layout is this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/horiz"
            android:scrollbars="none">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Space
        android:layout_width="500px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <com.alfbishop.testing.testbbdd.ListasBotones
            android:id="@+id/AperturasRadio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
     </com.alfbishop.testing.testbbdd.ListasBotones>
    <Space
        android:layout_width="500px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Could you help me to find a solution?